# What's the max size of a Xively datapoint value

Tags: xively

I would like to write JSON to a datapoint value in Xively (so I can store a value dictionary in a single datapoint). What is the max size (e.g. string length) I can write to a datapoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

255 bytes, so basically 255 utf-8 characters.